# Last row of inline-block divs is shifted right

Tags: html, css

I have googled and searched on SO about this issue, and I just cant fix it.

It is really, really annoying and driving me crazy!!

I have a menu that is made up of several blocks. These are created by divs with display: inline-block

I have also tried float:left, but I need these all centered on the screen and this doesn't work.

With my inline-block, it works fine and adjusts to the size of the screen by making more rows - but the last row is always offset by 2 pixels!

This is my code and css...

```
<div class="menublock"><div class="menublock-inner" style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i><br /><br /><b>home</b></div></div>
<div class="menublock"><div class="menublock-inner" style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i><br /><br /><b>home</b></div></div>
<div class="menublock"><div class="menublock-inner" style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i><br /><br /><b>home</b></div></div>
<div class="menublock"><div class="menublock-inner" style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i><br /><br /><b>home</b></div></div>
<div class="menublock"><div class="menublock-inner" style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i><br /><br /><b>home</b></div></div>
<div class="menublock"><div class="menublock-inner" style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i><br /><br /><b>home</b></div></div>


.menublock {
width: 170px;
height: 150px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
display: inline-block;
background: #0074bc;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
vertical-align: top;
}

.menublock-inner {
padding-top: 30px;
}
```

And the result is...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you set up a JS Fiddle to reproduce this error?

Comment: it's actually working fine https://jsfiddle.net/56qotr4u/

Comment: It also works making a test on my browser. Your code works great!

Comment: works fine but give more details if possible, like broswer/version etc also could the fiddle be using more/less css etc like a reset code or could yours have more interrupting it etc here's another one http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/wgPyzx

Comment: Also meant to post this:  https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: This is testing on iPhone Safari iOS 10. @SimonDavies Doing nothing to the code, but just removing the line breaks inbetween the lines of code fixed it!! Crazy! Change your comment to an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: always gets me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this old link always gets me:

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

So id do mine a little different like:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 610px;
}

.menublock {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  }
  .menublock-inner {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: rgba(0,94, 184, 1);
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    }
    .icon {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .fa {
        
      }
      span {
        padding-top: 5px;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper">
  
  <!-- block -->
  <div class="menublock">
    <div class="menublock-inner">
      <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span>home</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- eo: block -->
  
  <!-- block -->
  <div class="menublock">
    <div class="menublock-inner">
      <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span>home</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- eo: block -->
  <!-- block -->
  <div class="menublock">
    <div class="menublock-inner">
      <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span>home</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- eo: block -->
  <!-- block -->
  <div class="menublock">
    <div class="menublock-inner">
      <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span>home</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- eo: block -->
  <!-- block -->
  <div class="menublock">
    <div class="menublock-inner">
      <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span>home</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- eo: block -->
  <!-- block -->
  <div class="menublock">
    <div class="menublock-inner">
      <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" style="color:#fff;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <span>home</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- eo: block -->

</div>
<!-- eo: wrapper -->
```

Comment: can you say which method do you use from specified link? although i can't reproduce the issue with html/css given in question

Comment: because of this little issue etc i do this type of thing different as my eg shows, of i would used float instead of display or Flex-box if not concerned about older browsers